# Is $Th(\mathbb{Z}, <) \cup Diag (\mathbb{Q}, <)$ satisfiable?

Tags: logic, model-theory

I want to show that there exist $\mathcal{M} \equiv (\mathbb{Z}, <)$ and an order-preserving embedding $\sigma :\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathcal{M}$.

It's enough to see that $ Th(\mathbb{Z}, <) \cup Diag (\mathbb{Q}, <)$ satisfiable and by compactness that each subset $\Sigma_0$ is satisfiable. WLOG, $\Sigma_0$ isthe single formula

$$\varphi \wedge \psi(a_1, \cdots a_n)$$

such that $(\mathbb{Z}, <) \vDash \varphi$, $(\mathbb{Q}, <) \vDash\psi(a_1, \cdots a_n)$ and $\psi(a_1, \cdots a_n)$ is Boolean combination  of atomic formulas. Finally I know the atomic formulas are $x = y$ of $x < y$.

My question is: Is $(\mathbb{Z}, <)$ a model of $ Th(\mathbb{Z}, <) \cup Diag (\mathbb{Q}, <)$? Why?

Comment: what does Diag mean ?

Comment: @mercio Diagram.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to talk about $(\mathbb Z, <)$ being a model of $\operatorname{Th}(\mathbb Z,<)\cup \operatorname{Diag}(\mathbb Q, <)$ without giving an interpretation of all the constant symbols (i.e. all the rationals) in $\mathbb Z$. If we could do this, and the result were a model, it would amount to finding order preserving embedding of $\mathbb Q$ into $\mathbb Z$ itself. But it's pretty clear that no such embedding exists.

So $\mathbb Q$ doesn't embed into just *any* model of $\operatorname{Th}(\mathbb Z, <).$ However, the problem is correct that there is *some* model that it embeds into, and since we know what all models of $\operatorname{Th}(\mathbb Z,<)$ look like, we can find an explicit example. The models of $\operatorname{Th}(\mathbb Z,<)$ are anything of the form $(L\times \mathbb Z, \prec),$ where $L$ is a linearly ordered set and $\prec$ is the dictionary order on $L\times \mathbb Z.$ So, for instance, $\mathbb Q\times \mathbb Z$ is a model of $\operatorname{Th}(\mathbb Z, <),$ and you can embed $\mathbb Q$ into that easily.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your aswer. If I change $Th(\mathbb{Z, <})$ for $T$ an $<$-theory extending the theory of linear orders such that $T$ has infinite models, should I use compactness?

Comment: @TomRyddle Sure, and there was nothing wrong with using it on this problem either. My answer was more directed at the question at the end and how to make sense of the result (and of course I did not prove the fact that $(\mathbb Q\times Z,\prec)$ is a model of $\operatorname{Th}(\mathbb Z,<)$.)